# Rails: Showing the latest deploy date in web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, deployment, updatedate

I'd like to show in our app when the latest production deploy was made, as a means of showing an ongoing commitment to improvement, etc, etc.

Off the top of my head I'm thinking of getting a last_updated_at from one of the files, but I'd like to hear other thoughts.

#### What's the best way to get the date of the latest production deploy dynamically?

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Thanks to mpd who pointed me on the right direction.*

For those interested in doing something similar, this is a quick and dirty method that probably can be refined and refactored.

In `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` put this method in the private section:

```
private 

def app_last_updated_at
  if File.exist?(RAILS_ROOT + "/REVISION")
    timezone = "Mountain Time (US & Canada)"
    @app_last_updated_at = File.atime(RAILS_ROOT + "/REVISION").in_time_zone( timezone )
  else 
    @app_last_updated_at = "Not Long Ago."
  end
end
```

Obviously, replace the timezone with your own (or you can do something fancy for individual user timezones).

In order to have this run all the time I use a `:before_filter` and put it at the top of your `application_controller.rb`.

```
before_filter :app_last_updated_at
```

And then to actually show this last updated at date, you just throw this or something like it in a layout or a partial or whatever:

```
<%= 
unless @app_last_updated_at.nil? 
  if @app_last_updated_at.is_a? Time 
@app_last_updated_at.to_s(:long)
  else
@app_last_updated_at 
  end
end
%>
```

Hopefully, this helps others. I'm not keen on having it run in the `ApplicationController` for every access, so suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: A suggestion for not having it run for every request: You could set a constant APPLASTUPADTEDAD in a file in "config/initializers".

Comment: @TheMahrvin Thanks for the reminder - I did exactly this not too long ago - I'll update this answer with a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it pretty easily with Capistrano. Take a look at this link I think it does exactly what you want [Deployment date](http://www.rubyfleebie.com/last-deployment-date/)

Comment: Thanks for the link man. I'm going to post a more detailed solution from my efforts later today.

Comment: np, I look forward to seeing your results.